# How to make my own ng-change and ng-model in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement a directive with its own model and change attribute (as an overlay for ng-model and ng-change). It works apparently fine but when the function of the father scope is executed and some variable of the scope is modified in it, it is delayed, the current change is not seen if not the one executed in the previous step.

I have tried adding timeouts, $apply, $digest ... but I can not get it synchronized

```
angular.module('plunker', []);

//Parent controller
function MainCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.directiveValue = true;

  $scope.textValue = "init";

  $scope.myFunction = 

  function(){

    if($scope.directiveValue === true){

      $scope.textValue = "AAAA";

    }else{

      $scope.textValue = "BBBB";

    }
  }
}

//Directive
angular.module('plunker').directive('myDirective', function(){

  return {

    restrict: 'E',

    replace: true,

    scope: {

      myModel: '=model',
      myChange: '&change'

    },   

    template: '<span>Check<input ng-model="myModel" ng-change="myChange()" 
       type="checkbox"/></span>', 
   controller: function($scope) {

   },
   link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

     var myChangeAux = scope.myChange;

     scope.myChange = function () {
       setTimeout(function() {
         myChangeAux();
       }, 0);
     };

   }
});

// Html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <my-directive model="directiveValue" change="myFunction()"></my-directive>
  <div>Valor model: {{directiveValue}}</div>
  <div>Valor texto: {{textValue}}</div>
</body>
```

The correct result would be that the "myFunction" function runs correctly

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/q3IqRCIhwLChlGrkDxyO?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AngularJS' `$timeout` which is a wrapper for the browser default `setTimeout` and internally calls `setTimeout` as well as `$digest`, all at the right time in the execution.

Your directive code should change as such:

```
angular.module('plunker').directive('myDirective', function($timeout){

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      myModel: '=model',
      myChange: '&change'
    },   
    template: '<span>Check<input ng-model="myModel" ng-change="myChange()" type="checkbox"/></span>', 
    controller: function($scope) {
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var myChangeAux = scope.myChange;

      scope.myChange = function () {
        $timeout(myChangeAux, 0);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

[Docs for AngularJS $timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)